# Specific direction from a point: If 'slope' is not sufficient, then what is?

Tags: java, point, angle

The plan was to calculate the slope between the two points(character and cursor), convert it to an angle to the horizontal, and depending on that angle, switch to a specific character sprite so that it appears to be pointing at the cursor(example: 0-30 degrees, one sprite. 30-60 degrees, another sprite. 60-90 another, etc). The problem I encountered afterward was that the slopes could mirror each other in a way.

I realized the (now seemingly obvious) problem was that having the character at point A and the cursor at point B would have the same slope/angle as the character point B and the cursor at point A. It had no way of knowing the direction to point.

[image: Illustration of my issue]

I'm at a loss as to what to do from here. The simplest solution would be to have it so that the direction of the player wouldn't be found out through this way(whether it's facing right or left), but through the arrow keys, but I'm saving that as a last resort as it would cause problems with quickly aiming.

Comment: Can you find the location of the cursor and compare that to the location of the sprite?

Comment: The coordinates of the cursor and sprite are used to calculate the slope between them at first, if that's what you mean. In what way would I go about comparing them?

Comment: I'd convert to angle -- 0-360 degrees, or 0 to 2 pi.  Then there is a direction implied, and you can also gracefully handle a vertical vector (and a "vector" is what you're talking about).

Comment: (java.lang.Math implements the `atan2(x,y)` method that cleanly converts x and y (delta) coordinates to an angle in radians.)

Comment: You could also add a "sense", which could be a boolean. `true` means you're following the slope (for example) left to right and vice versa. That said, it'd be easier to just have a 360 degree direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double deltaX = point1.x - point2.x;
double deltaY = point1.y - point2.y;
double angleInRadians = java.lang.Math.atan2(deltaX, deltaY);
double length = java.lang.Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
```

Comment: Good answer, trig was the first thing I thought of too. +1

Comment: For `length`, you can just call `point1.distance(point2)`. You don't need to calculate it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use sprite/cursor location along with slope to solve this.

Pseudocode:

```
if(slope is positive and cursor is to the right of sprite)
{
   sprite should face right (first quadrant, 0-90 degrees)
}
else if( slope is positive and cursor is to the left of sprite)
{
   sprite should face left (third quadrant, 180-270 degrees)
} 
//etc
```